# Domain decomposition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In order to solve the $1$-D problem 
\begin{align*}
u^{''}=f \in (0,1),\\
 u(0)=u(1)=0,
\end{align*}
$f\in L^{2}(0,1)$, if we choose our solution space to be $H^{1}(0,1/2)\times H^{1}(1/2,1)$ and then get a variational formulation. Does it coincide with the
 weak formulation on $H^{1}_{0}(0,1)$? Or some interface condition to be imposed to get a solution? Here I assume our original solution is enough regular i.e. in $H^{2}$. I have some confusion. Please some body help

Comment: What is meant by "the standard Galerkin variational formulation"? Sounds enigmatic outside the context of Galerkin approximations. While $u\in H^1(0,1)$ is not required, you are supposed to hint at what you expect to call a solution of your bvp, no matter how weak it might be: $u\in H^s(0,1)$ with $s\in (0,1)$, or $u\in L^2(0,1)$, or otherwise.

Comment: Dear Sir, I have just edited my problem. Kindly ponder. I want a resulting solution in $H^{1}_{0}$ by choosing my solution space as $H^{1}(0,1/2)\times H^{1}(1/2,1)$. Thank you

Comment: A variational formulation requires some functional, variation of which leads to the appropriate weak formulation. Both the functional and the weak formulation correspond to one and the same classical formulation. Nothing can be done until some correct classical formulation has been chosen. It seems that your classical formulation is to be something like $$u''=f(x),\;\;x\in (0,1/2)\cup(1/2,1),\;\;u(0)=u(1)=0 $$ with two interface conditions at $x=1/2$, e.g., $$ u(1/2-0)=\alpha u(1/2+0),\;\;u'(1/2-0)=\beta u'(1/2+0).$$